# SQl Developer gets ORA-01017

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL Plus makes login but SQL Developer doesn´t

I am using:

- Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 18.4.0.0.0
- SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0
- SQL Developer 20.2.0.175.1842

Using SQL Plus I can make login

- user: system as sysdba
- psw: oracle

Using SQL Developer I get ORA-01017

[image]

But months ago I made login everyday with SQL Developer.

I am using a Windows 10 with a few other users.

How can I make login with SQL Developer again?

Comment: Are you sure of the pwd? upper/lower case issues?

Comment: If you are connecting successfully via `sqlplus` on the database server without having to authenticate over TNS, then your two tests are not comparable.

Comment: Yes, I tried lowercase and uppercase. Maybe the point is @JeffHolt 's comment

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious but you are using a **different connection type** in SQL*Plus compared to SQL Developer.

In SQL*Plus you're doing this:

```
user: system as sysdba
```

However, in the SQL Developer connection dialog your `tipo de conexion` is set to `Basico`. Open the dropdown and choose `Sysdba`, and you should be fine.

The reason for this is that SYSTEM is a power-user account, and so needs an elevated connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection with sqlplus is utilizing os credentials, and is not even checking the username and password.  The fact that you are requesting a connection 'as sysdba' tells oracle to see if the requesting OS user is a member of the os group DBA.  If it is, let 'm in.

```
[oracle@vbol83-01 ~]$ sqlplus fubar/thisiswrong as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Jan 24 08:31:50 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL>
```

In fact, you don't even need a username/password at all for this connection:

```
[oracle@vbol83-01 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Jan 24 08:34:11 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
```

On the other hand, your SQL Dev connection is going across the network, and requires the credentials that are presented match what is in the oracle password file.

I don't know what your system looked like "months ago", or what you might have been doing differently then.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is not th best solution, but it could be usefull.

I didn´t resolve how to connect SQl Developer using "system" user, but I have how to use SQL Developer.

First, use SQL Plus to create a new user, for example "system_user_1":

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
create user system_user_1 identified by system_user_1;
GRANT RESOURCE TO system_user_1;
grant create session to system_user_1;
grant unlimited tablespace to system_user_1;
grant sysdba to system_user_1;
```

Then, add new conection to SQL Developer for "system_user_1" as SYSDBA:

Finally you can use "system_user_1" to create new regular users:

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
create user regular_user_1 identified by regular_user_1;
GRANT RESOURCE TO regular_user_1;
grant create session to regular_user_1;
grant unlimited tablespace to regular_user_1;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]